# C# application control local network iOS

Tags: c#, android, ios, sockets, local-network

I'm in the middle of the process of making an application on Windows in C# and I want to make an IOS and an Android program. Things are going well, but I'm kind of stuck on implementing the requirements for proper network communication.

I've searched a lot on sockets and I'm quite sure that I have to use that but I don't know for sure. I can't really find much about it. So I was wondering if you guys could point me in the right direction.

So my question basically is how to establish connection and send the proper functions.

Comment: What are you _specifically_ having issues with? There are plenty of examples on how to use sockets out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably looking for an RMI Framework. (Remote Method Invocation)

What it basicly does is it's calling methods from other applications.
For example: on your pc you call rmi.DoDisPlayMessageOnPhone("Hello!")
your application on the phone will execute that method (you implemented -duh-).
It makes networking simple and you don't have to bother about networking that much.

Here is an RMI Framework that I use too:
[SimpleClientServer (Scs)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/153938/TCP-Server-Client-Communication-Usage)

It has a great example. Just read carefully and you will have networking in no-time :P

Comment: This is exactly what I'm searching for! Awesome!