# Does anyone have any experience writing "companion" apps - a iOS app that talks to a Windows app?

Tags: c#, ios, .net, network-programming

first question after 7 years being a member and about a century being a parasite just taking the goodness of everyone elses answers!

I have an extensively developed and complex windows application written entirely in C#. It is networked using a UDP socket for discovery and then a WCF style service that can be either self hosted or discovered. This is working just fine and dandy.

While the entire process in this application can be handled by one very skilled operator, it is definitely advantageous to have some lackeys do the simple tasks - and I mean there's some really simple tasks. In the past this was achieved by printing a report and having the lackey go around and tick the list, and report back when everything was accounted for. Now there's a fairly simple screen that does the job well. "Tomorrow" I want to give the lackey an iPad with a 'lite' version of the application that only performs these select single functions. The biggest complexity is that the iPad needs to know live of any changes to the list that happen on the 'master' computer, and the 'master' computer should know when the lackey completes the list. This happens in the simple screen I've got, but obviously was a problem with the report, and in practice I've noticed the client base don't have a heap of computers to be using so they almost always fall back to the report-based process.

I am currently refactoring the main application for a new major version and changing a few things around, so I'm evaluating my options for the networking functionality.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27453665/c-sharp-application-control-local-network-ios) that talks about "Simple Client Server" (SCS) library to do Remote Method Invocation which looks like a perfect replacement for my WCF service in the windows-to-windows scenario, and it looks like I could adapt it into an iOS app (it'll be in C# after all). This project is quite old though and doesn't really *help* me work out the iOS side of things (maybe I'm lazy, maybe it's having twin babies).

My toolset is Visual Studio 2019 using C#. My existing application is WPF for the visual wow abilities, but really the UI is not at issue here. Architecturally I have a sync service class that will run on the 'master' application and all clients, including the one on the master, will go through that service to perform data operations so I have a single point to jam in what I need. I have been .net'ing for 15+ years, but this will be my first attempt at the iOS project in Visual Studio.

I am aware I could use the existing UDP discovery method to find the server and then write RESTful services, however I want the companion app to be live and receive event notifications and this doesn't seem like a very efficient way of doing that.

For gamers out there, Bethesda released a companion app on the iPad for Fallout 4 which is exactly the concept - on the iPad app you can interact with your Pip-boy, see the map, change your inventory around, but you can't actually play the game from it.

Does anyone have any guidance, specifically or in general, as to how I might go about writing a "companion" app using my toolset that can easily talk to my windows app?

Comment: On a related note I've also found it hard to find an actual first steps how-to write an iPad app using Visual Studio on a Windows machine, so if I can get some good answers to this question I might have to do a "How I did it" tutorial to pay it forward.

Comment: You can't write an iOS app with just a windows machine. You need to either use it on a mac, or you need to connect your windows PC to a mac instance: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/

Comment: Thanks @ekke I am aware I need a mac for build, there's plenty of cloud services for that. What I'm after is networking between the apps.

Comment: How about just build a responsive web app, now that's cross platform, the front end web app can call your existing WCF backends, and no need to deploy to your lankey's devices.

Comment: Thanks @Markuzy, I've already excluded the lite options and settled on needing the native performance. Even if I did go with Cordova or similar, that hasn't helped to actually easily talk with my windows app.

Comment: Oh man, my first question on this platform and I've got no answers, one comment about needing a Mac, and one comment suggesting I don't do what I've asked in two weeks. I thought if anywhere out there might have the answer or experience it would be SO...